# csv.DictWriter producing a blank 0byte csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a bit of code that should be processing a non-empty csv file. However, when I run this code It generates a blank 0byte csv file. I am on python 3 using excel with OS X. This is the DictWriter code:

```
with open(self.SALES_SHEET,'wb') as sf:
     fieldnames = ['first_name','last_name']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(sf, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Zach' ,'last_name': 'B'})
```

I am at a loss for what my error could be. No matter how many ways I rewrite this, I end up with a blank csv.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that code shouldn't even _run_ in python 3.  You should get something like `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, because you're opening the file in the wrong mode.

Comment: @DSM I have changed it to `w` the csv produced is still blank.

Comment: Yeah, but since you said the first code was generating a blank csv and I'm very confident that code never executed in Python 3, it's hard to know what other things you think are going on which aren't (e.g. maybe you're looking at the file before you leave the `with` block and so it isn't flushed yet).  Please make your code a self-contained [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure the file is being saved where you think it is?

Comment: @BrenBarn I am positive. I can verify it with the timestamp updates.

Comment: @Sleepy-Z Could you please elaborate on what role Excel might play in this? How are you trying to use Excel with your Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did the modification of the `wb` to `w` and `self.SALES_SHEET` is a valid value, it should work. I ended up with a proper CSV with the following code:

```
import csv

csv_filename = "test.csv"

with open(csv_filename,'w') as sf:
     fieldnames = ['first_name','last_name']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(sf, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Zach' ,'last_name': 'B'})
```

Comment: I think it might be an OS/Excel version related issue. I have experienced a similar bug with the working program: if I were to save the file through excel's exit save notice, the file would immediately be turned blank, if I ran the program again. I decided to finally learn pandas and now my data sheets are looking great.